# HoloEverywhere - Action menu padding issue

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am having an unexpected issue with `ActionBarSherlock`. When I use  `Holo.Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`, it is ok and will look like

[image]

but if I choose `Holo.Theme.Sherlock.Light`, I am getting some `Padding` issues in the `DropDownListView`, like this :

[image]

I dont want that much `Padding` in between the `ListView` items

I have tried making a `CustomTheme`, but its not working

`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Holo.Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
</style>

<!-- style the items within the overflow menu -->
<style name="DropDownListView" parent="Holo.ListView.Light">
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
</style>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug of ABS. It looked like that only in the emulator. On a real device it will work fine